# Slicing below the limits of a numpy array

Tags: python

Let's say `a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])`

Is there a mechanism of slicing below the lower boundary?
E.g: `a[-2:3]` -> `[0,1,2]`

`x x {x x 0 1 2} 3 4 5 x x x x`
`{x x 0 1 2}`
`{0 1 2}`

PS: I know that negative indexes are relative to the end of the array

Comment: I really don't get your question. a[:3] gives what you want, right? And it seems that you understand the negative slicing mechanisms... So what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @PySeeker, here's a question that would benefit from this feature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58007431/extract-only-the-ps-and-the-ds-from-a-section-of-a-known-message-p-p-p-d-d-d

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @PySeeker, a similar feature that is very useful and just works is this: np.array([0,1,2,3])[:1000]. Accessing elements beyond the length of the array

Comment: @DanielMesejo, here's an example where this would be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58007431/extract-only-the-ps-and-the-ds-from-a-section-of-a-known-message-p-p-p-d-d-d

Comment: Why I dont get is why you are forced to used a negative index why don't just, a[s if s > 0 else 0:e], or something of the sort.

Comment: @DanielMesejo, quite often the slicing indexes are the result of some arithmetic. If the result of that arithmetic produces negative indexes would be great if the slicing also worked, in order to avoid conditionals. It gets worse because negative indexes are interpreted in a different way in Python so I am not even able to handle that exception.

Comment: Somewhere along the way is going to be a conditional, explicit or implicit.

Comment: I guess there are only two solutions. Either override the default mechanism of handling negative indexes, as suggested by @kabanus, by implementing my own, or avoid accessing elements in the negative side by "shifting" my data to the right as much as required (prepending items to the beginning) and use only positive indexes.
In principle, I think this second option would avoid conditionals.

Comment: @DanielMesejo, I think the second option I'm proposing might avoid conditionals.

Comment: Shifting wont solve your problem the slice -2:3 is empty

Comment: @DanielMesejo, the performance cost is a great point

Comment: @DanielMesejo, if you insert 2 elements and then access -2+2:3+2 works.
Generalising: a[-2+inserted_elems:3+inserted_elems]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use `max` to handle auto-generated negative values?

```py
a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
x = -2
a[max(0, x), 3]  # this is equivalent to a[:3]
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such mechanism. One option is this wrapper:

```
def my_slicer(arr,i,j):
    if i < 0: i = 0
    if j >=arr.shape[0]: j = arr.shape[0]-1
    return arr[i:j]
```

Of course, this assumes a single dimension.